# Не могу разбить строку на массив с числами

Tags: javascript

```
//Строка которую нужно разбить: "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"

function highAndLow(numbers){
  var num = String(numbers).trim();
  num = String(numbers).split('');
  function getMaxValue(num){
    var max = num[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (max < num[i]) max = num[i]; 
    }
    return max;
}
  return parseInt(getMaxValue(num));
  // вывод: 9, а не 542, так как строка
  // разделяется на символы, а не на отдельные числа
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//Строка которую нужно разбить: "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"

function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var num = String(numbers).trim();
  num = String(numbers).split(' ');

  function getMaxValue(num) {
    var max = +num[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      if (max < +num[i]) max = +num[i];
    }
    return max;
  }
  return parseInt(getMaxValue(num));
  // вывод: 9, а не 542, так как строка
  // разделяется на символы, а не на отдельные числа
}

console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста что значит +num[i] . А именно "+"

Comment: @АртемПересунько Сокращение для `Number(num[i])`.